# Providing tests as part of a library

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

Suppose an interface like:

```
public interface Fooer {
  void foo();
  boolean isFooed();
}
```

This is part of a Java library that I'm writing. Users of this library are supposed to implement this interface and pass objects into my library.

I want to provide a way for users to test *their* implementation to hold the invariants *my library code* assumes.

Following the above example:

```
Fooer f = getUsersFooer();
f.foo();
// f.isFooed() MUST return true now
```

Is it possible, and if so, feasible or even acceptable to provide such tests as part of the library?

(I don't know whether these would be considered unit tests or integration tests ... they test the modifications made by a single method using getter methods or very primitive non-mutating methods)

Sure, I can write classes like

```
public class TestFooer {
  public static boolean test(Fooer f) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

but is there a "standard way", using the usual testing frameworks (JUnit, ...) ?

Comment: I don't know if there's a standard way, but fwiw, rather than a static method I would create an abstract class with a single abstract method, createFoo(), and then concrete test methods. Or some sort of DI -- there may be integrations between DI frameworks and testing frameworks.

Comment: I think that there is no standard way of doing this, but IMHO the static method is a good way of doing this. You should not use any JUnit code within your library and make assertions by simply throwing an AssertionsError. This makes your test usable with TestNG and JUnit.

Comment: These tests are integration tests: They test whether the assumptions about the other component hold.  In contrast, in unit-testing, when you create doubles (mocks, stubs), you implement them according to your assumptions about the other component.  That is, unit-testing is not suited to identify misconceptions about other components.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common pattern used to check the compliance of implementations of some spec. This is called a TCK, [Technology Compatibility Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit). I've not looked at the code of many TCKs, but I've seen them often using [TestNG](https://testng.org/).

There was a recent addition to JUnit 5.8.0-M1 that allows to define test suites that can be used for this, too.

Your TCK has a **non-test** dependency on your API and `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter` (at least `5.8.0-M1`) plus `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite` (at least `1.8.0-M1`). The tests are not in `src/test/java` but `src/main/java`. Then you add a suite class to your TCK like:

```java
package org.example;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@SelectPackages("org.example")
public abstract class TestCompatibilityKitSuite {}
```

Note that this class doesn't have to be abstract, I just think it makes the intended usage more clear.

The implementation then has a dependency on the `api` and a `test` dependency on the `tck`. To run the tests, add a class like:

```java
package test;

import org.example.TestCompatibilityKitSuite;

class TckTest extends TestCompatibilityKitSuite {}
```

The TCK has to load the implementation. A good way to do so is by using a `java.util.ServiceLoader`. For a full example look [here](https://github.com/t1/junit-tck-mre).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this looks very interesting! Is it also possible to put the API, TCK and implementation into different packages? I moved `Impl1.java` from `org.example` to `org.example.impl`, but then I get an *java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.example.Api: Provider org.example.Impl1 not found at org.example.ApiTest.<init>(ApiTest.java:9)* error when building the implementation project. I'm not sure what's going on there: Why does it think that `Impl1` is in the `org.example` package at all?

Comment: @efie: Yes, they can be in different packages. Your question is about how the `ServiceLoader` works, actually. The fully qualified name of the impl is in a file in the `META-INF/services` that has the name of the API. It looks like you should update contents of that file to `org.example.impl.Impl1`.